# Use sequence-functions to find certain sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

I want to split a list of positive Integers into sublists whose
ascending elements differ by 1.

```
list = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 8, 1, 2};
```

This can be done easily using `Split`

```
Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &]
```

> {{1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {4, 5, 6}, {5}, {8}, {1, 2}}

But how can we get the same result

(a) with one of the Sequence-functions (`SequenceCases`, `SequenceSplit` or `SequencePosition`) - or, if this is not possible,

(b) What other options do we have?

Comment: so `differ by one` and are `ascending`?

Comment: yes, exactly, I will specify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SequenceCases` with a similar condition like the one for `Split`:

```
list = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 8, 1, 2};

SequenceCases[list, s_ /; OrderedQ[s, #2 - #1 == 1 &]]
```

> `{{1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {4, 5, 6}, {5}, {8}, {1, 2}}`

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 8, 1, 2};
```

**Using `SequenceReplace` or `SequenceCases`:**

```
SequenceReplace[list, {b__ /; 
    ContainsOnly[Differences[{b}], {1}]} :> {b}]
```

---

*Result:*

```
{{1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {4, 5, 6}, {5}, {8}, {1, 2}}
```

---

The documentation says:

`ContainsOnly[{},list] always returns True`

without which this would not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 8, 1, 2};
```

---

Using `SequenceSplit` with the following condition:

```
SequenceSplit[list, s : {b__ /; MatchQ[Differences[{b}], {1 ...}]} :> s]
```

> `{{1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {4, 5, 6}, {5}, {8}, {1, 2}}`